# Cognos 10 : How to get Cognos module names with the users who use them from the repository?

Tags: repository, cognos

I need to get these infos from the Cognos repository (AS or CS ?) and also the number of simultaneous connexions to a module for a certain period.

Example :

Period : from 01/03/2015 to 30/03/2015

User   | Module        | Nb connections

user 1 | Query Studio  | 5

user 2 | Report Studio | 2

user 3 | Event Studio  | 3

Thanks in advance !

Comment: There is nothing like that logged.  You can look in the audit database to see about report executions using report studio, etc, but there's nothing to tell you how many people are using a give studio.

Comment: Yeah i know that we can get report executions with the audit package. But it's a pity we can't retrieve the execution details of the modules in the repository. :/